# JQuery easy ui tree drag and drop feature hangs for large tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, tree, jquery-easyui

I am using [J Query Easy UI](http://www.jeasyui.com/) for creating tree structure and using drag & drop feature. It works fine for tree with less than 100 nodes . But I have tree with approximately 7 thousand nodes and in such cases the drag n drop feature hangs and web page becomes not responding.

Suggestions or alternatives are welcome.
TY